# Meaning of the 'action of the force' in physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, terminology, definition

Example:

> The potential energy of this object is created **due to the action of** the force $F$.

Why not?

> The potential energy of this object is created **by** the force $F$.

Comment: You're correct, that's another way to say it. There are a lot of different ways to say the same thing in English. (Personally, I disagree with both of these wordings, but I wouldn't go so far as to call them strictly wrong.)

Comment: @d_b, what do you suggest for academic writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

> The potential energy of this object is created **by** the force F.

It is unclear, at least to me, what $F$ is in the example is supposed to be or what type of potential energy (e.g., electrostatic, elastic, gravitational) is involved.

But let's assume it is the gravitational potential energy (GPE) of an object a height $h$ near the surface of the earth, i.e., GPE=$mgh$, and that $F$ is an external (to the earth-object system) force that raised the object from the ground to rest at the height $h$.

In the GPE example, it is the negative work done by the action of force of gravity that directly results in the increase in GPE of the earth-object system, not the external force $F$. (I say "results" because created is a poor term as energy is never "created", only changed in form).

On the other hand gravity obtains the energy for conversion to GPE due to the action (positive work done on the object) by the external force $F$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy (such as gravitational potential energy when you lift something) is stored not only due to a force being present but due to the force *moving* the object over a distance:

$$U_g=mgh.$$

This displacementight $h$ might be what is referred to as the "action" that the force does. It's a bit unusual choice of words but I guess it can make sense.

Comment: Thanks! How do you suggest writing the above example in formal academic writing?

Comment: @John If you have understood the concept then it shouldn't be a huge issue to write it out professionally yourself, no?

Answer (score 1):

You need a force to move a body from it's stable equilibrium, which is later stored as PE.
That force is referred here.